# Pandas: remove characters based on conditions in a DataFrame

Tags: python, pandas

I have a DF that looks like this:

```
ids
-----------
cat-1,paws
dog-2,paws
bird-1,feathers,fish
cows-2,bird_3 
.
.
.
```

I need to remove all the ids that have a **-** or **_** in the dataframe. So, final data frame should be

```
ids
-----------
paws
paws
feathers,fish
.
.
.
```

I've tried using lambda like this:

```
df['ids'] = df['ids'].apply(lambda x: x.replace('cat-1', '').replace('dog-2', '' )...)
```

But this is not a scalable solution and I would need to add all the ids with dashes and underscores into the above. What would be a more scalable/efficient solution?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a [regex pattern](https://regex101.com/r/Op3lKk/1):

```
df.ids.str.replace('\w*[-_]\w*,?', '')
```

Output:

```
0             paws
1             paws
2    feathers,fish
3                 
Name: ids, dtype: object
```